# Retrieving the value of "SkipEndUserAcceptance" from a JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to retrieve information from a JSON, but the specific location of the information may vary. Here is an example of the data I have:

| id | templatevalues |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"complexTypeProperties":[{"properties":{"Value":"NoDisruption","AttributeName":"Urgency"}},{"properties":{"Value":"SingleUser","AttributeName":"ImpactScope"}},{"properties":{"Value":"448928","AttributeName":"RegisteredForActualService"}},{"properties":{"Value":"10146","AttributeName":"Category"}},{"properties":{"Value":true,"AttributeName":"SkipEndUserAcceptance"}}]} |
| 2 | {"complexTypeProperties":[{"properties":{"AttributeName":"RegisteredForActualService"}},{"properties":{"Value":"SingleUser","AttributeName":"ImpactScope"}},{"properties":{"Value":"NoDisruption","AttributeName":"Urgency"}},{"properties":{"Value":"10154","AttributeName":"Category"}},{"properties":{"Value":"true","AttributeName":"SkipEndUserAcceptance"}}]} |
| 3 | {"complexTypeProperties":[{"properties":{"Value":"SingleUser","AttributeName":"ImpactScope"}},{"properties":{"Value":"NoDisruption","AttributeName":"Urgency"}},{"properties":{"Value":"721846","AttributeName":"RegisteredForActualService"}},{"properties":{"Value":"10146","AttributeName":"Category"}},{"properties":{"Value":"true","AttributeName":"SkipEndUserAcceptance"}}]} |
| 4 | {"complexTypeProperties":[{"properties":{"Value":"SingleUser","AttributeName":"ImpactScope"}},{"properties":{"Value":"SlightDisruption","AttributeName":"Urgency"}},{"properties":{"Value":"2854102","AttributeName":"RegisteredForActualService"}},{"properties":{"Value":"10153","AttributeName":"Category"}},{"properties":{"Value":"435331","AttributeName":"ServiceDeskGroup"}}]} |
| 5 | {"complexTypeProperties":[{"properties":{"Value":"NoDisruption","AttributeName":"Urgency"}},{"properties":{"Value":"SingleUser","AttributeName":"ImpactScope"}},{"properties":{"Value":"10146","AttributeName":"Category"}},{"properties":{"Value":"597224","AttributeName":"RegisteredForActualService"}},{"properties":{"Value":true,"AttributeName":"SkipEndUserAcceptance"}}]} |
| 6 | {"complexTypeProperties":[{"properties":{"Value":"NoDisruption","AttributeName":"Urgency"}},{"properties":{"Value":"SingleUser","AttributeName":"ImpactScope"}},{"properties":{"Value":"10146","AttributeName":"Category"}},{"properties":{"Value":"597224","AttributeName":"RegisteredForActualService"}},{"properties":{"Value":false,"AttributeName":"SkipEndUserAcceptance"}}]} |

I need to retrieve the value of "SkipEndUserAcceptance" from a JSON. This value can be either "false" or "true". Currently, I'm using the expression :

```
TEMPLATEVALUES::jsonb -> 'complexTypeProperties' @> '[{"properties":{"AttributeName":"SkipEndUserAcceptance","Value":"true"}}]' AS "SkipEndUserAcceptance"
```

to retrieve it. However, the returned value appears to be unpredictable.

Could you please suggest a solution for retrieving the value of "SkipEndUserAcceptance"? Additionally, if the attribute "SkipEndUserAcceptance" is not present, it should be set to "false".

Current output :

| id | SkipEndUserAcceptance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | false |
| 2 | true |
| 3 | true |
| 4 | false |
| 5 | false |
| 6 | false |

Expected output :

| id | SkipEndUserAcceptance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | true |
| 3 | true |
| 4 | false |
| 5 | true |
| 6 | false |

fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6AacERW43QoJ5Ggb3X4Dys/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES)

```sql
(
   select (j ->> 'Value')::boolean 
   from jsonb_path_query(templatevalues, '$.complexTypeProperties[*].properties') as j
   where j ->> 'AttributeName' = 'SkipEndUserAcceptance'
 )
```

to extract the `SkipEndUserAcceptance` value and `coalesce` it to `false` for the expected result. Here it is:

```sql
select id, 
 coalesce((
   select (j ->> 'Value')::boolean 
   from jsonb_path_query(templatevalues, '$.complexTypeProperties[*].properties') as j
   where j ->> 'AttributeName' = 'SkipEndUserAcceptance'
 ), false)  as "SkipEndUserAcceptance"
from the_table;
```

See [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jz9Zb5PWwE5uFJr71tyoTC/0).

Answer (score 1):

Use jsonb_to_recordset to create a table from the array:

```
SELECT id
     , COALESCE((MAX(properties ->> 'Value')
                 FILTER (WHERE properties ->> 'AttributeName' = 'SkipEndUserAcceptance'))::BOOL
    , FALSE) AS skipenduseracceptance
FROM tbl_temp
   , JSONB_TO_RECORDSET(templatevalues -> 'complexTypeProperties') jtr(properties JSONB)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```